# Do I need to write all the child objects in a class in realm as well?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Following the example code as shown:

```
// Define your models like regular Swift classes
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = 0
}
class Person: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var picture: NSData? = nil // optionals supported
  let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

// Use them like regular Swift objects
let myperson = Person()
let mydog = Dog()
mydog.name = "Rex"
myperson.dogs.append(mydog)

// Persist your data easily
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  // do I need to add this statement??
  realm.add(mydog)
  realm.add(myperson)
}
```

Do I need to persist the mydog object as well, or that Realm is smart enough to know that it is a new child object of the myperson and it will persist it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need to persist the actual dog object, if you already persist an object containing it.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer. What if dogs contain new objects and also objects returned from filter (e.g. realm.Objects(dogs).filter(dogs.age = 3))? Realm will know which ones are new and which ones are already in the database?

Comment: I believe Realm effectively makes an object graph. Therefore if a given object changes it's completely overwritten.  Realm doesn't need to diff.

Comment: My pleasure. Anymore questions let me know

Comment: @Woodstock How about deletion part? Will it delete child items while deleting the parent object?

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes indeed.

Comment: It is not deleting. I had to query the sub entities and delete them separately

Answer (score 1):

For the users who are wondering about cascading delete, the answer is `NO`.

Realm supports cascading write but `NOT` delete. For delete you may have to query all the relations and delete one by one.